# Agora cloud recording api https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/:api_id/cloud_recording/acquire CORS block when I make request through browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, agora.io

My Agora cloud recording api https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/:api_id/cloud_recording/acquire works through postman but CORS block when I make same request through browser, I have not access of backend
Following is the code of my Angularjs post request

let url = 'https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/:app_id/cloud_recording/acquire';

```
            $http({
             method: 'POST',
             url: url,
             data: data,
             headers: {
              'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*/*',
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token,
                'Accept': 'application/json',
            }
             }).then(function (success) {
                 console.log(success)
             }, function (error) {
                 console.log(error);
             });
```

Comment: `I have not access of backend` then you'll need to make a request by using your own server to proxy the request - easy to do, depending on what *your server* is running

Comment: Hi Jaromanda, Can you please guide me here how can I achieve this.

Comment: what's your server side language?

Comment: I am using nodeJS as server side Language.
By the way I have fixed this problem in to step
1. Send client side request to my server
2. then from my server send request to agora server
I think the provider was blocking request send from client side So I send request from my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your domain does not have access to accessing API. please contact your API provider or try to call API from the server-side.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's exactly what the OP needed to do to solve his issue.

Answer (score 0):

By the way I have fixed this problem in to step 1. Send client side request to my server 2. then from my server send request to agora server I think the provider was blocking request send from client side So I send request from my server